# Does ss5 proxy server support IPv6?

Tags: centos, ipv6, socks5-proxy

Doesn't seem to work. My server have IPv6 activated and working. 
curl -6 directly also works, but not with the proxy.
I have check the log and the error is "no IPv6 support"

Comment: Do you authenticate via passwd?

Comment: As a side note, ss5 looks like an incredibly buggy piece of software, not to mention old. I suggest you find an alternative, because both aspects, as outlined (age and bugginess) are security issues.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Apparently, for some very odd reason, it works with LDAP authentication, but not with passwd. Maybe try that.

Comment: I read somewhere else mentioning the same fix. I will try that.